# What is the difference between a DataGridView Location.X and Left property?

Tags: c#

From what I read in the help of a `DataGridView.Location` :

> Gets or sets the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the control
>   relative to the upper-left corner of its container.

From what I read in the help of a `DataGridView.Left` :

> Gets or sets the distance, in pixels, between the left edge of the
>   control and the left edge of its container's client area.

I don't see what the difference is?

Comment: For any Control ctl, _ctl.Left is equal to ctl.Location.X_ and _ctl.Top is equal to ctl.Location.Y_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Location` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes [`Point`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx) which contains [`X`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Y`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties.

[`Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.left%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is equal to `X` of the `Location` property.

Comment: that's is about the guess I had. Wanted to be sure I didn't missed something else. Thanks a lot! More simple to edit x and y separetely! Will mark it as answer as soon as I can

Comment: Location of shapes can vary (center, upper left, ...) but default location is the upper left corner of shape.  The x direction increments as you go towards the bottom of the monitor, while y dimension increments from left to right.  A control like a DGV inherits the shape properties.